# best way to share data between c codes

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi3

I have 3 C code running on a RPI. They all start at boot and do some stuff (e.g. reading some data and driving an LCD)

I have implemented the codes separately but now I need to share a 30 byte buffer to be shared between them.

what is your advice to do this?

```
program1.c<-----------> program2.c<-----------> program3.c
buff[30] <----------->   buff[30] <-----------> buff[30]
```

Comment: Are you willing to build the 3 C source files into a single executable?  What are your performance needs?

Comment: There are lots of different approaches with advantages and disadvantages. Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Approaches

Comment: no i just need 3 executable that run separately and share a data buffer

Comment: The easiest approach is to simply use a shared file. But really it depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i have already read about IPC, there are lots of examples and concepts in this regard, but i am wondering which one to choose that fulfill my need mutex,semaphore,socket,unix domain socket,pipe,shared memory

Comment: Either run the code of each program as a separate thread inside a new program and they can immediately see a shared lump of memory because they are in the same process. Or use `mmap()` in three separate programs to allow them all to access a lump of shared memory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use shared memory IPC, which simply allows you to access the same physical memory from multiple cooperating processes.  I say cooperating because they need to be careful about synchronization, or reads may observe partially written data etc.  Here's one tutorial: http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/memory/shared-memory

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to implement an IPC between those processes. Personally, I would like to go with `FIFO` ( a named pipe ) because they implement the queue structure for you. So, you can focus more on interpreting the data and less on sync problems.

[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/choosing-a-transport) might help you.